# Running a vba method from python with long path in Windows 10

Tags: python, path

## Scenario

In an attempt to execute method `main` from `module` of `example.xlsm` from python file `convertOds.py`, I am experiencing slight difficulties. The path to the excel file is "too long" as it is longer than 218 characters. Now I could work around it and make a temp folder at `c:/temp` but then I lose some generality, e.g. what if the pc it runs on has no `c:` drive. So I am trying to run the excel method from a deep path regardless.

## Code execution steps

The code is executed by opening Anaconda, browsing to the directory of the `example.xlsm`, the `convertOds.py` is located in the same directory as the `example.xlsm` file. So for example:

```
E:
cd "E:\long path of more than 218 characters/"
python convertOds.py
```

## Code

The `convertOds.py` consists of:

```
import xlwings as xw

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = r'E:\long path of more than 218 characters/example.xlsm'
    wb = xw.Book(file)
    macro = wb.macro("main")
    macro()
```

## Error

The code yields the following error message when I execute it from anaconda with python 3.7:

> > File ">", line 8, in Open
> >     pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Cannot open the file because the file path is more than 218 characters. Try shortening the path or filename.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

So the first and second thing I did was enable long paths at `regedit` and `gpedit.msc` and reboot, according to the following procedure:

```
# 1.1 Press: start>Type: run>Type: gpedit.msc <enter>>Go to: Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Filesystem
# 1.2 And enable: "Enable Win32 long paths".
# 2. Then also enable long paths in regedit:
# 2.1 Press: start>Type: regedit<enter>>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
# 2.2 And enable: LongPathsEnabled
```

However that still results in the error described above.

## Question

Is there a way to execute a method `main` from `module1` of an `example.xlsm` from python even if it has a long path >260?

Comment: `cd` into a subdir along the path, execute from there?

Comment: The `convertOds.py` is executed by indeed first browsing to the directory of the `examle.xlsm` (which also contains the `convertOds.py`) and then it is executed with:`python convertOds.py`. That results in the error described in the question. Thank you, I have included the explicit running instructions.

Comment: ... and succeeds in that case? Or not?

Comment: In that case the error is thrown.